# Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets based on the same rows conditional format

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet where I have tasks, and I prioritize those tasks based on high, medium, and low levels. I currently use conditional formatting for this, so if I select from a drop-down "HIGH", the whole row will be highlight red.
However. I would like to add another condition, for the same row. I want to now click the checkbox indicating that this task is complete, and once I do, it would change to another color.

I tried using the `AND` formula, but I think that the conditions compete against one another, so even when I click the checkbox, the row will still stay red because of the priority condition.
What can I do?

Comment: Welcome. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if an answer addressed your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `AND`.
You just need to **create 2 rules for your range** (*or maybe more?*) using the following formulas:

- **for the checkbox: `=COUNTIF($D16, "=TRUE")`**
- **for the "HIGH": `=$A16="HIGH"`**

You must also **note the order** these rules are applied on the attached image.

[image: row medium]

As you see you get to highlight the whole row.

If, on the other hand, want to have **just the checkbox cell highlighted**, you should use formulas as shown on the following image.
Can you spot the differences?

[image: single cell]